# Changing the time to GMT+05:30 in twitter tool in cartodb

Tags: carto, twitter

I am much more interested in exploring geotagged twitter maps using cartodb. By default, We will be giving a search term as well as the From/To (Date with time) usually it will be 30days. In this From/To, time will be in GMT+0 and my time is in GMT+05:30. I would like to know how to change the default GMT+0 settings in this twitter tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CartoDB Twitter importer reads the time in GMT+0, so if you are interested in getting data for a specific period in another timezone, make sure you substract or add the respective hours to convert it to GMT+0.

CartoDB will treat the input as GMT and no time conversions will be performed internally.

Comment: By the way, I just opened this issue https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb/issues/7025 because after your question I thought the messages in the UI were confusing.